# Regarding C++ Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was just wondering. If the derived class uses public inheritance to inherit from a base class, and it also redefines one of the base class public member functions, which does the compiler use if the instance of the derived class calls print() for example? And print is defined in the base class and redefined in the derived class? Thankyou very much!!

Answer (score 3):

By redefining a base class member function in the derived class, the new definition **hides** the old definition.

Therefore, in the scope of the derived class, only the new definition can be seen.

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
  void print() { std::cout << "b \n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  void print() { std::cout << "d \n"; }
};

int main(void)
{
  Base b;
  Derived d;
  Base *pb = &d;
  Derived *pd = &d;

  b.print(); // Calls Base::print()
  d.print(); // Calls Derived::print()
  pb->print(); // Calls Base::print()
  pd->print(); // Calls Derived::print()

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: would this change if print was declared to be virtual though in the base class?

Comment: Of course. If `print` was virtual, calling `print` from a pointer would call the respective `print` function based on the dynamic type of the pointer (i.e. the type of the actual object the pointer is pointing to). `pb->print()` would then call `Derived::print()`.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks so much!!! It would not affect dot notation though right? I tested it out and it doesn't. Just want to make sure. Thanks again <3

Comment: It might be worth noting that the book Effective C++ covers this issue (and many others) in extensive detail.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler uses static type of the object that to determine which function to call. Any name including member functions declared in the derived class hides declarations with the same name in the base class.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() : data( 10 ) {}
    void f( char ) { std::cout << "Base::f( char )" << std::endl; }
    void f( int ) { std::cout << "Base::f( int )" << std::endl; }
    int data;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : data( "Hello World!" ) {}
    void f( double ) { std::cout << "Derived::f( double )" << std::endl; }
    std::string data;
};

int main() 
{
    Base b;
    b.f( 0 );
    b.f( 'A' );
    std::cout << b.data << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    Derived d;
    d.f( 0 );
    d.f( 'A' );
    std::cout << d.data << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    Base *pb = new Derived;
    pb->f( 0 );
    pb->f( 'A' );
    std::cout << pb->data << std::endl;

    delete pb;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Base::f( int )
Base::f( char )
10

Derived::f( double )
Derived::f( double )
Hello World!

Base::f( int )
Base::f( char )
10
```

Using virtual functions instead of non-virtual provides polymorphism.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() : data( 10 ) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void print() const { std::cout << data << std::endl; }
    int data;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : data( "Hello World!" ) {}
    void print() const 
    {
        Base::print();
        std::cout << data << std::endl; 
    }
    std::string data;
};

int main() 
{
    Base b;
    b.print();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    Derived d;
    d.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Base *pb = new Derived;
    pb->print();

    delete pb;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10

10
Hello World!

10
Hello World!
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Vlad!! Quick question. Did the compiler treat the char A and 0 as a double? (for the derived) Thanks!!

Comment: @Kevin Cheng The member function in the derived class hides member functions in the base class with the same name. So they do not take part in the overloading resolution.